# Way of finding size of a string other than split separated by hyphens?

Tags: javascript, string, data-structures

In the size() function, I have used split then finding the size of the array. Is there any other way or logic to find the size of the string separated by hyphens(---) other than split.

```
var Stack = function(){
    this.callStack='';
}

Stack.prototype.push = function(val){
    if(this.callStack==''){
        this.callStack = this.callStack.concat(val);
    }else {
        this.callStack =  this.callStack.concat('---', val);
    }
}

Stack.prototype.pop = function(){
    this.removeThis = this.callStack.lastIndexOf(('---'));
    this.str = this.callStack.slice(this.removeThis+3);
    this.callStack =  this.callStack.substring(0, this.callStack.lastIndexOf('---'));
    return this.callStack;
}

Stack.prototype.size = function(){  
    var sizes = this.callStack.split('---');
    return sizes.length;
}

//This will tell the latest element inserted in the stack:
Stack.prototype.peek= function(){
    var peekabu = this.callStack.slice(this.callStack.lastIndexOf('---')+3);
    return peekabu;
}

var stackInst = new Stack();

stackInst.push('Ankit');
stackInst.push('Ashu');
stackInst.push('Ash');
stackInst.push('Pikachu');

console.log('Size of the Stack is:', stackInst.size());
```

Comment: *"...without using split or anything outside of strings..."* That's an odd restriction. Why?

Comment: just want to know the possible ways.

Comment: Why are you even using a string to store the values here? Why not use an array directly?

Answer (score 0):

> ...without using split or anything outside of strings

That's an odd restriction.

You could use `replace` to replace all non-hyphens, and take the length of the result:

```
return this.callStack.replace(/[^-]/g, '').length;
```

If you mean the number of `---` occurrences, not just the number of hyphens, divide by 3 *(naturally this assumes there won't be other hyphens in there)*:

```
return this.callStack.replace(/[^-]/g, '').length / 3;
```

But to be certain of only counting `---`, you could pass a callback to `replace`:

```
let size = 0;
this.callStack.replace(/---/g, function(m) {
    ++size;
});
return size;
```

But again, it's an odd restriction, and these are odd solutions as a result.